# How to parse such XML with boost.Qi and call functions named as tags?

Tags: c++, boost, xml-parsing, boost-spirit-qi

so I know there are official tutorials on [Boost.Qi XML parsing](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___error_handling.html) but I steel quite do not get how to parse with it such XML:

```
<host url="http://www.site.com"/>
<run app="myApp" version=443 url="/folderName/innerFolder/myApp.exe"/>
<folder name="folderName" version=443>
<folder name="innerFolder" version=443>
<file name="innerFile.txt" version=443 url="/folderName/innerFolder/innerFile.txt">
<file name="myApp" version=443 url="/folderName/innerFolder/myApp.exe"/>
</folder>
<file name="fileName"  url="/folderName/fileName.exe" version=442/>
</folder>
```

It looks quite simple but I steel do not get how to parse my xml..( What I need is simple - call a function (called with same name as tag like file() of host()) I need to sent to functions objects like:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, std::string, void*> variant_type;
std::map<std::string, variant_type> tagObj;
tagObj["url"] = 10;
```

So - how to make boost.Qi parse my XML and call my functions while parsing?

Comment: I'm not sure if boost::spirit is the right tool for your task. Sure, it is possible and they provide a minimalistic example of parsing a small subset of XML. I think you should use Spirit when there is no parser for your target language available, and use a fast, complete, well-tested, optimized parser for XML. [RapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/) is nice for example an integrates well with Boost.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got a working example yet (I am going through the xml parser example this morning too)  but I would say you want to change this rule

```
qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> start_tag;
```

to

```
qi::rule<Iterator, tag_struct(), ascii::space_type> start_tag;
```

where tag_struct is a `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` that accepts things like `folder name`, `version` `url` etc  Then the code from the [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/mini_xml1.cpp) should then be more or less the same - you will need to change the xml_mini_printer for output.  I will have a go at this myself as an exercise.  Will update if I get anywhere.

EDIT: Bah I'm stuck!

Comment: with impatience I wait for your code sample!=) Thank you for help!